# Saving Outlook Emails as ".msg" not as "File"

Tags: vba, outlook

I've got this block of code to go through all the emails in my "Today" folder in Outlook, then save all the emails (.msg) to a folder named as the sender name.

Sometimes the files are saving with the file type "file".

How do I fix this to make sure the emails are saved as .msg files?

[image: Screenshot of the "file" file type]

[image: Screenshot of its properties]

```
Sub SaveAttachments()
'https://www.fontstuff.com/outlook/oltut01.htm
'Declare Variables
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim Savefolder As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Today")
i = 0

'Stop script if there are no emails 
If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Display the number of emails
MsgBox Inbox.Items.Count, vbInformation, _
    "Number of Emails?"

'Go through each email
For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    'Create a path for the save folder
    Savefolder = "C:\Users\work\Desktop\22_11_18\Test\" & Item.SenderName
    'If the email has attachments, then create a folder
    If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        MkDir Savefolder
        'If the folder already exists, skip to the next statement
        On Error Resume Next
    'Save the email as a .msg file
    Item.SaveAs Savefolder & "\" & Item.Subject & ".msg"
    End If

Next Item
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error if you remove `On Error Resume Next`? I also don't see any indication that you're removing characters that aren't valid in a path. Such as `:` in "Re:"

Comment: Sometimes I do get an error because the folder already exists and the script attempts to make a new folder with the same name (sometimes I get multiple emails from the same sender); I've found that using the On Error enables me to get past this issue.

That didn't occur to me at all! I'll adjust the script to fix that, hopefully that is the cause.

Comment: I changed `.Subject` to `.ConversationID` and the problem has been fixed. Thank you very much!

Comment: On Error Resume Next should **always** be followed by a subsequent On Error Goto 0 after the line that can cause a beneign or recoverable error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subject if the characters in the subject are all valid.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SaveMail_ContainingAttachments_ValidSubject()

'Declare Variables
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim targetFolder As Folder
Dim itm As Object
Dim atmt As Attachment

Dim strSaveFolder As String
Dim validSubject As String

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set targetFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set targetFolder = targetFolder.Folders("Today")

'Stop script if there are no emails
If targetFolder.Items.count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in " & targetFolder & ".", vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Display the number of emails
MsgBox targetFolder.Items.count, vbInformation, "Number of Emails?"

'Go through each email
For Each itm In targetFolder.Items

    'If the email has attachments, then create a folder
    If itm.Attachments.count > 0 Then

        'Create a path for the save folder
        strSaveFolder = "C:\Users\work\Desktop\22_11_18\Test\" & itm.senderName

        ' Bypass error if the folder already exists
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir strSaveFolder

        ' Discontinue error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
        ' Let unknown errors generate then fix them
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' Replace or remove invalid characters
        ' Possible options "_" or " " or "" ....
        validSubject = ReplaceIllegalChar(itm.subject, "_")
        If validSubject <> itm.subject Then
            Debug.Print itm.subject
            Debug.Print validSubject
        End If

        'Save the email as a .msg file
        itm.SaveAs strSaveFolder & "\" & validSubject & ".msg"

    End If

Next itm

End Sub

Private Function ReplaceIllegalChar(strInput, strReplace)

    Dim RegX As Object

    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True

    ' Replace with another string
    ReplaceIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

ExitFunction:

    Set RegX = Nothing

End Function
```