# Save Outlook Mailitem to local folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code does everything I want: pulls email, saves attachments, extracts files
EXCEPT save the original email to the folder fDest.  I seem unable to see the solution.

This seems to be the problematic line as it won't save the email:
"mi.SaveAs fDest2, olMSG"

```
Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim fDest As Variant
    Dim j As Variant
    Dim sh As String
    Dim FileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim Tracker As Workbook
    Dim fSheet As Sheets
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim strFilePath
    Dim fTracker As Workbook
               
    strDate = InputBox("Enter Date in format dd-Mmm-yyyy", "User Date", Format(Now(), "dd-Mmm-yyyy"))
    strFilePath = "\\namdfs\CARDS\MWD\GROUPS\GCM_NAM\2021\05 May\"
    fTrackerName = "Inquiry.Tracker.SWPA.Violations.May.2021.xlsx" '

    On Error Resume Next
        Set fTracker = Workbooks(fTrackerName)
        'If Err Then Set fTracker = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath & fTrackerName)
    On Error GoTo 0
        'Windows(fTrackerName).Activate
      
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders("GCMNamLogs").Folders("Inbox")
        
    fDest = "C:\Users\jb76991\Desktop\Violations_Emails\"
    fUser = UCase(Environ("username")) & ":" & Chr(10) & Now()
        
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict("@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" & strDate & "%'")
        'Debug.Print fDest & i & ".msg"
        If i.Class = olMail Then
            Set mi = i
            fDest2 = fDest & mi.Subject & ".msg"
            mi.SaveAs fDest2, olMSG
            For Each at In mi.Attachments
                'do something with attachments but i've commented it out
            Next at
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Completed")
    
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me how to save the original emails that are being filtered?

Comment: Are there characters in `mi.Subject` which are not permitted as part of a filename?  What is the exact error message you see?   Take a look at the function `ReplaceIllegalChar` here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422235/saving-outlook-emails-as-msg-not-as-file

Comment: Tim Williams, there are no illegal characters.  I'm using the same name (or trying to) that already exists. "Run-time error '-2147286788 (800300fc)': The operation failed.

Comment: @Ted AAARGH!  I was WRONG!  Yes, there were invalid characters.  Once I corrected them it worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be sure there are no invalid characters in the filename. See [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more information. So, I'd suggest using the `Replace` method available in VBA before passing anything to the `SaveAs` method.

Another point is that you need to specify unique file names to each email. Make sure the generated file name is unique for a folder.

Comment: I have debugged the object and mailitem object names and there are no invalid characters.  I am admittedly poor when it comes to handling mail objects.

Comment: What is the actual argument passed to the `SaveAs` method?

Comment: AAARGH!  I was WRONG!  Yes, there were invalid characters.  Once I corrected them it worked fine...